# Azure Worker Role Testing

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

Can anyone suggest tools to Test worker role functionality on Azure?
I want to test the worker role after deployment not on local machine.

lets take an example, we have a library of songs. and I have created worker role to delete the songs those are added before 1 year. so to test this functionality, is there any tool available to test the worker role.

like we use SOUPUI to test the Web service functionality.

Kindly help thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may want to elaborate what do you want to test in your worker role once it is deployed in the cloud?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, lets take an example, we have a library of songs. and I have created worker role to delete the songs those are added before 1 year. so to test this functionality, is there any tool available to test the worker role.

Comment: like we use SOUPUI to test the Web service functionality.

Comment: Please modify your question to include as much details as possible instead of putting them in comments. It will help you get better answers. HTH.

Comment: Why don't you try the exact same testing techniques, using the worker's IP instead of your internal server's? Have you tried this? Was there a problem?

Comment: @Panagiotis- SOUPUI can be used to Test Worker Role? I don't have much experience on Azure. As a Tester not worked on Azure before. Got my first task to find Tools available to test Worker Role. Do u have any idea which tools can be used to test Worker Role.