# How do i access Azure worker role to test without using Web role?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I want to test only the worker role without accessing/calling throw web role.

let take one scenario where a client requested to create worker role to process the data (i.e. to insert data in DB, to do batch processing). Here client have web role created they just want worker role from us.

We created the worker role on Azure which inserts data in DB (like: First Name, Last Name, Company, Mobile No., Address).

Now testers want to test the worker role without Web Role because we do not have web role and we didn't created web role. we know that the web role will provide FirstName, LastName, Company, Mobile No., Address to worker role.

Could you please help how can our testers test the Worker Role.

Thanks

Comment: what did you deploy in there? did you create an api? you can use tools like Fiddler or so to enter the payload perhaps? Did you open de Worker role publicly? are you allowing traffic on endpoints?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Worker Role Testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178502/azure-worker-role-testing)

Comment: We created a cloud service which consist worker role and published the same on cloud. Not opened worker role publicly.

Comment: so no endpoints on which you can fiddle or connect different websites too?

Answer (score 0):

Worker roles and Web roles are nearly the same thing, the difference being Web roles have IIS configured while Worker roles don't. There's absolutely no need to have worker role input originate from a web role instance.

If you want to access an app / api / etc. running in your role instances (whether worker role or web role), you must either open public-facing endpoints or access your role instances via a virtual network.

How you actually set up your endpoints, or set up your testing, is up to you.